# Realm XCODE plugin does not find DB for newly created simulators

Tags: xcode, realm

I have installed the Realm plugin for XCode to easily having access to the `Realm Browser`. 
It works as long as I use the simulators installed during the Xcode installation.

But if I use "add additional simulators" from the XCode menu, the Realm plugin is no longer able to open the Realm Browser.
I get the following error: `Unable to find Realm file. You must launch iOS Simulator with app that sues Realm.`

Any ideas how or where to fix this issue. 
Thanks in advance John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it myself. I went to 'Add Additional Simulators', added a new iPhone 5s one, and then built and ran the app using the same Simulator. Once it was open, I clicked 'File>Open Realm...' and it worked.

One thing to be aware of is that not only does the app need to be open in the Simulator, but Realm needs to have actually run and produced a Realm file inside the app container before you can use the 'Open Realm...' button. Because 'Add Additional Simulators...' will create a new copy of your app from scratch, it's easily possible that the app container itself hasn't been populated with a Realm file until you've interacted with the app some more.

I hope that helped!

Comment: Hi TiM, thanks for that feedback. I will double check what you just have mentioned and maybe that is the whole secret. Cheers John

Comment: Hi TiM, so I had time to double check and YES it looks like the reason was exactly as you have described the different behaviors. Thanks.